# Racket - can a contract on a function argument depend on the value of another argument?

Tags: racket, contract

Let's say I have a function:

```
(define (func x y)
    ...)
```

I would like to constrain the arguments so that:

- **x** is a positive integer
- **y** is a positive integer which is less than or equal to **x**

The first constraint is obviously trivial, but is there any way to set up the second constraint with Racket's contract system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You want to use *dependent contracts*, in Racket expressed using the [`->i`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/function-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._-~3ei%29%29) contract combinator. The contract for your function as you described it would look like this:

```
(->i ([x (and/c integer? positive?)]
      [y (x) (and/c integer? positive? (<=/c x))])
     [result any/c])
```

Here’s an example of the kind of error that would occur when inappropriately applying the function contracted with the above contract:

```
> (func 1 2)
func: contract violation
  expected: (and/c integer? positive? (<=/c 1))
  given: 2
  in: the y argument of
      (->i
       ((x (and/c integer? positive?))
        (y
         (x)
         (and/c integer? positive? (<=/c x))))
       (result any/c))
  contract from: (function func)
```

For dependent contracts, all arguments and the result need to be named so that they can be referred to in other clauses. The `(x)` within the second argument clause specifies that the contract for `y` *depends on* the value of `x`, so you can use `x` within the contract specification for `y`.

The full grammar for `->i` is available [in the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/function-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._-~3ei%29%29), which has plenty of additional features. It also has some examples, including one that is very similar to the example in your question.